# SDL application showing black window

Tags: sdl, codeblocks

I am making a breakout game with C using SDL.I am using Code::Blocks.My application does run properly when I am running it from within the IDE.But when i try to run the release .exe file from bin/release folder it only shows a black window .Nothing shows up in the window.There is not any problem with my coding of course since it does run from within code blocks.So i guess I will need to set up something in the build options or something to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using relative paths to access external assets make sure your [working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) is what you expect when you run outside of Code::Blocks.